# No se como hacer que mi api devuelva un string como datetime

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Tengo que devolver un datetime desde un string en mi proyecto de asp.net para feedear un calendario que solo acepta datetime.
El string es un numero de dos digitos que representa el día de vencimiento de un producto. Lo convierto con el siguiente código a DateTime, pero muestra un error que lo entiendo, pero no se como solucionarlo.

"Can not implicity convert system.datetime to string"

No puedo aplicar dt2.ToString(); Porque el plugin de calendario no lo leería ya que solo acepta DateTime. Gracias!!

```
public IHttpActionResult GetPolizas()
    {
        var polizaDto = _context.Poliza
            .Include(m => m.UsoVehiculo)
            .Include(m => m.Compania)
            .Include(m => m.MedioPago)
            .Include(m => m.Cliente)
            .ToList();


        foreach (var poliza in polizaDto)
        {
            var fecha = poliza.Vencimiento;
            fecha = DateTime.Now.Month + "-" + poliza.Vencimiento + "-" + DateTime.Now.Year + " "+ "00:00:00";

            DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha,
                    "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            poliza.Vencimiento = dt2;

        };



        return Ok(polizaDto);
    }
```

Comment: y que es poliza.vencimiento?? trata de no usar var... recuerda que c# es mejor si tipeas las variables tal como son. Me imagino que debe ser un entero ya que estas tratando de concatenar el mes (string)? + poliza.vencimiento (string dia) +  año y hora

Answer (score 1):

Si la propiedad `Vencimiento` es un Datetime quizas lo que quieras hacer es algo como esto

```
foreach (var poliza in polizaDto)
{
    string fecha = string.Format("{0}-{1}-{2} 00:00:00", DateTime.Now.Month, poliza.Vencimiento.Day, DateTime.Now.Year);

    DateTime dt2 = DateTime.ParseExact(fecha, "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

    poliza.Vencimiento = dt2;

};
```

como veras se utiliza el `poliza.Vencimiento.Day` para tomar solo el dia